Flutter share: IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains 'Path'
I use share_plus to share a captured widget (Uint8List). The code below shows how I am saving the "image" to a temp directory, and then trying to share it (two ways, using XFile(path) and XFile.fromData(data)).
Both started to throw an exception after I updated to Flutter 3.22.0, as shown in the logs. (not sure the exception is thrown exactly after the update, but that part of the code hasn't changed in a while and the only thing I can think of is the flutter update I made recently).
The same code works without problems on iOS phones with iOS 17.5 - and used to work on Android as well. I didn't update that part of the code in a while.
Logs:
I/flutter ( 5943): PlatformException(Share failed, Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/app.id/cache/share_plus/drawing.png, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/app.id/cache/share_plus/drawing.png
I/flutter ( 5943):  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:849)
I/flutter ( 5943):  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:452)
I/flutter ( 5943):  at dev.fluttercommunity.plus.share.Share.getUrisForPaths(Share.kt:188)
I/flutter ( 5943):  at dev.fluttercommunity.plus.share.Share.shareFiles(Share.kt:96)
I/flutter ( 5943):  at dev.fluttercommunity.plus.share.MethodCallHandler.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandler.kt:46)
I/flutter ( 5943):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
I/flutter ( 5943):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
I/flutter ( 5943):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMes
E/flutter ( 5943): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Error creating temporary file


I/flutter ( 5943): PlatformException(Share failed, Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/app.id/cache/share_plus/4cd-1fde-861b-f1ecb4ceeecd.octet-stream, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/app.id/cache/share_plus/4cd-1fde-861b-f1ecb4ceeecd.octet-stream

Code
Future<ShareResult> shareImage(Uint8List bytes) async {
    try {
      String path = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;

      File tempFile = File('$path/drawing.png');

      tempFile.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
      return await Share.shareXFiles(
        [XFile.fromData(bytes)],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return Future.error('Error creating temporary file');
    }
  }

And
Future<ShareResult> shareImage(Uint8List bytes) async {
    try {
      String path = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;

      File tempFile = File('$path/drawing.png');

      tempFile.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
      return await Share.shareXFiles(
        [XFile(tempFile.path)],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return Future.error('Error creating temporary file');
    }
  }


I found out what was the issue.
The provider was not that: I never had the file provider in my manifest, that's already declared in the share_plus package.
I never used an older version than the one declared: 9.0.0.
It was happening with all devices, different emulators and physical devices as well, and different OS versions: from API 31 up to 34.
The problem was I had both share and share_plus plugins.
I don't know why the share functionality worked, but my best guess is that updating Flutter SDK broke the share plugin.
Upon removing the dependency to share and keeping only share_plus, the share functionality was up and running for Android as well.
Thanks for your support.
